# Condition for Axiom of Specification

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set theory,the Axiom of Specification claims the existence of the subset under the condition $P(x)$, I am wondering under what kind of condition, we can directly say that this set is not empty without proving there is an element in it. For example $\{x|x\in A,x=a\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axiom schema of *Specification* (or *Separation*) assert the existence of a set $B$ such that, for all set $A$ :

> $B = \{ x|x \in A \land \varphi(x) \}$

provided that $B$ is not free in $\varphi$.

In your example, if we set $\varphi(x) := x = a$ we surely get a non-empty subset $B$ of $A$, and exactly $B =  \{ a \}$, *provided that* $a \in A$.

Comment: I mean with what kind of condition we can exclude the case it is not an empty set directly, without proving

Comment: what kind of condition can we say that it is not empty without proving.

Comment: @89085731 - "in principle" ... none. Nothing prevent us to use an empty $A$ in the axiom schema; thus, whatever "condition" you choose, you will never get a non-empty subset of $A$. If you have proved that $A$ exists and it is not empty, you have to "manufacture" a suitable condition.

Comment: @89085731 - consider the "tautological" condition $x=x$. Applying the axiom schema we get $B= \{x|x∈A∧(x=x) \}$ i.e. we "separate" the full $A$ from itself (i.e. $B=A$). But if we have no previous established the fact that $A$ is not-empty, it is still possible that $B=A=\emptyset$.